What does 145 mean in "Tsuu T'ina 145"?
"Tsuu T'ina Nation 145 is an Indian reserve of the Tsuut'ina Nation in southern Alberta, Canada."
What does 145 stand for in "Tsuu T'ina 145"? I understand "Tsuu T'ina" means "a lot of people."

Might this be just an address? If, as the WP article notes, 146 Avenue SW is the southern border, then 145 Avenue SW would be the next road allowance to the north and inside the reserve. I don't know much about the system of the Dominion Land Survey, but maybe someone at [gis.se] can help.

Hm. Almost all reserve names end with a number, some of them preceded by an explicit "No." Nonetheless, they seem not to be unique (for example, there is a "Abitibi 70" and a "Alder Creek 70"), and distinct from the database numbering CIRNAC uses. For that, Tsuut'ina Nation has the number 432, and the reserve the number 06639.

FWIW, the First Nation Profiles website by the Canadian government has a Definitions page that lists as an attribute of a reserve the "reserve number": "A unique number used to identify a particular reserve." Duplications may be clerical errors from back in the day? E. g., Alexander 134 was formed in 1882. It's imaginable that back then, people in different regions accidentally used the same number or such.

@HenningKockerbeck The Reserve Number on the definitions page is the extra field, i. e. the "06639" I quoted above. The "145" is listed in the Reserve Name field, not separated.
